Unknown CMake command "cmake_print_properties"
I'm trying to use the cmake_print_properties command for debugging purposes, but when I try to compile my project, I get the following error:
Preset CMake variables:

  CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug"
  CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS="ON"

-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.42.34435.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.42.34435.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.42.34433/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.42.34433/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (cmake_print_properties):
  Unknown CMake command "cmake_print_properties".

I made a small cmake file that results in the same error:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(
    TEST_PROJECT

    VERSION
    0.1

    DESCRIPTION
    "TEST PROJECT"

    LANGUAGES C CXX
)


cmake_print_properties(
    TARGETS 
        TEST_PROJECT
    
    PROPERTIES
        LANGUAGES
)

My cmake version in the terminal is cmake version 3.29.5-msvc4.
What am I doing wrong to not be able to use this command?

You are missing include(CMakePrintHelpers). You could google it faster than asking the question.

Thank you very much!
I hadn't found this information in my research, I looked at several forum posts, I looked at several website posts, not even the official page for this command has this information.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.31/module/CMakePrintHelpers.html
Anyway, thanks for the answer.
